# Is this SQL code update correctly while I update in one row?

Tags: sql

UPDATE Vaccine SET VaccineNo = 'Sinovac Dose 1' WHERE VaccineNo = 'SIND01';

The question for this code:
[image]

Comment: Yes. But you should have tried it before asking question.

Comment: what are the columns on the table? is there a 'description' column?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks correct but I think you misunderstood the question. The question asks you to update the **description** and *not* the VaccineNo. Instead, the query would look more something like this:

```
UPDATE Vaccine SET Description = 'Sinovac Dose 1' 
WHERE VaccineNo = 'SIND01';
```

Depending on what the description column name is.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a description field in the table as per the question. Something like:

```
UPDATE Vaccine SET Description = 'Sinovac Dose 1' 
WHERE VaccineNo = 'SIND01';
```

But your code is syntactically correct.